# GNOME GUI: Show Applications Button - Customizable Alternative?

Tags: launcher, dock

On the dock in Ubuntu, there is a button that says says "show applications" when you hover over it.

[image: Show Applications Button]

I noticed that there is a similar version of that on Macos, and it's called "Launchpad." I would like to customize my "Show Applications" screen, but it doesn't seem very customizable. Are there any apps that act as an alternative to this?
Thanks.

Comment: What would you want to achieve? What behavior would you wish to implement?

Comment: @vanadium Hi! Thanks for asking. I am looking for an app that is at least a bit customizable and has similar behavior to the "show applications" (ubuntu) or "launchpad," (mac). So basically I want a launcher that shows all the applications I have installed. I have tried Ulauncher and GNOME-Pie but I would also like to just see all my apps together. If you have any more questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Still not clear what you want functionally. Application Overview shows all your apps;  you can manually arrange them like you want - e.g change their order, combine them in groups, etc. Of course, the layout and visual appearance is what it is and can be changed with gnome shell themes and extensions only.

Comment: @vanadium The specific behavior I am looking for includes a better grid that stretches farther out on the screen so I can see more apps at once. I am also looking for application categories, which some GNOME extensions are able to do, but I can't find one that can do this with the applications overview. If you've ever heard of "slingshot" which is created for ElementaryOS, I am looking for something similar to that.